# Threading not running in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

Any idea as to why Jupyter isn't running my code?
I tried running the function "hello" separately and got it to run but can't seem to get the Timer to run it.

```
import time
from threading import Timer

def hello():
    print("hello world")
    
t=Timer(1,hello)
t.start()
```

[Picture of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsil3.png)

Comment: My psychic powers suggest your program is exiting before the timeout elapses.

Comment: That was it! Thank you! 
I added time.sleep() and that stopped the program from exiting before the time elapsed.